# Quadratic Equation Algorithm

Tags: algorithms, quadratics

I need help for developing an algorithm.

I'm drawing a given amount of line segments and I want them to decrese in length the more they get close to amount/2 and then to grow again until they reach the end of the loop.
The data I have are the amount of segments, the segment-min-length and the segment-max-length.

I think that this could be done with a quadratic equation with the vertex in coordinates (segments-amount/2,segment-min-length) and with the left arm of the graph intersecting the y-axis at coordinates (0,segment-max-length) and the right arm of the graph intersecting the vertical imaginary line drawn at x = segments-amount.

Now the challenge is to get this quadratic equation dynamically given these data (segment amount, segment-min-length, segment-max-length).

And that's where I am stuck.
How do I get the equation with these data?

If I haven't been clear enough please comment and I'll edit the question.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ y=a(x-b)^2+c $$

You say you want the minimum at $x=\frac{N}{2}$, I'm going to take the minimum at $\frac{N+1}{2}$ which is the standard middle value expression. Therefore $b=\frac{N+1}{2}$.

You want that minimum value to be $L_{min}$ so $c=L_{min}$.

Now if $N$ is even, this will produce a smallest line segment bigger than $L_{min}$, but perhaps the problem can admit such a solution. If not, you'll need to differentiate between $N$ odd and $N$ even in your code. When $N$ is even yoll need to live with an asymmetry in your lengths i.e. for $N=6$, taking $N=3$ to be the smallest length $L_{min}$, the first length will be smaller than the last length. You'll need to take that into account when finding $a$.

Substitution of the point $(N,L_{max})$ (realise that if $N$ even and you took $N=4$ to be the smallest length then you need to consider the point $(1,L_{max})$. Then

$$ L_{max}=a\left(N-\frac{(N+1)}{2}\right)^2+L_{min} $$

$$ a = \frac{4(L_{max}-L_{min})}{(N-1)^2}$$

So your on the fly formula is

$$ y= \frac{4(L_{max}-L_{min})}{(N-1)^2}\left(x-\frac{(N+1)}{2}\right)^2+L_{min} $$

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the answer! Just one thing: I don't get from where does that 4 in the a formula come out? Why is it a costant?

Comment: It comes from $(N-(N+1)/2)^2=((2N-(N+1))/2)^2=((N-1)/2)^2=(N-1)^2/4$.

Comment: Thank you very much bob! I've tried to develop my algorithm like this `length = ((4*(Lmax-Lmin)/((N-1)*(N-1))) * ((i - (N + 1)/2)*(i - (N + 1)/2))) + Lmin;` With these values `Lmin = 40; Lmax = 80; N = 7;` and being `i` the index of the loop I get these results: `111.11, 80, 57.78, 44.44, 40, 44.44, 57.778`. For any (odd) value I give to `N`I get the first value out of my range and I never get the last value near my Lmax. Do you happen to know why?

Comment: Looks like you may have zero indexed the loop? Because I used the point $(N,L_{max})$ the last element needs index $N$ to be consistent, so the first element should be indexed $1$. I've just reread your question, and whilst you do suggest a graph intersecting the $y$-axis at $L_{max}$, I think it is more natural to have the first length be indexed by $1$.

Comment: Yes that was the case, I was zero-indexing the loop. Now that I started from an index of 1 it works perfectly. Thank you very much!!!